# FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

I am trying to evaluate the following expression

```
X_r[y_all == "yes", 0]
```

and get the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:1:
>   FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a
>   boolean array index

What does it mean? I do WISH to use `y_all=="yes"` as boolean array index. Since it is warning me, it does something else.

What does it do?

**P.S.**

```
> np.shape(X_r)
(395, 2)

> type(X_r)
numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: That sounds like you might have a list instead of an array for `y_all`.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38734025/5962321): your array is actually considered as 'many times the entries 0 and 1' instead of a real boolean array. Your result is therefore only composed of repetitions of the two first entries in `X_r`.

As to why this happens... I don't know... any hint would be welcome!

Answer (score -1):

What is the type of y_all ? May be you just need to convert it onto `numpy.ndarray` type.

```
y_all=y_all.values
```