# NumPy boolean array warning?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, bitmask

I have a few numpy arrays, lets say `a`, `b`, and `c`, and have created a `mask` to apply to all of them.

I am trying to mask them as such:

`a = a[mask]`

where `mask` is a `bool` array. It is worth noting that I have verified that

`len(a) = len(b) = len(c) = len(mask)`

And I am getting a rather cryptic sounding warning:

`FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index`

Comment: That error indicates that you're trying to use a 0-dimensional boolean array as an index. The semantics of that operation are in the process of changing. How did you verify that `mask` is even a thing with a `len`?

Comment: Wait, no, wrong warning. Did you get a list for `mask` somehow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

False == 0, and True == 1.  If your mask is a list, and not an ndarray, you can get some unexpected behaviour:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> mask_list = [True, False, True]
>>> a[mask_list]
__main__:1: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index
array([2, 1, 2])
```

where this array is made up of a[1], a[0], and a[1], just like

```
>>> a[np.array([1,0,1])]
array([2, 1, 2])
```

On the other hand:

```
>>> mask_array = np.array(mask_list)
>>> mask_array
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> a[mask_array]
array([1, 3])
```

The warning is telling you that eventually `a[mask_list]` will give you the same as `a[mask_array]` (which is probably what you wanted it to give you in the first place.)

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much, makes sense. Fixed by casting the list to a numpy array via `mask = np.array(mask_expression, dtype = bool)`